# Assign string elements as integers to variables in single line

Tags: python

This might be a silly question but I couldn't figure out how to do it (or if it is even possible).

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a = ['32132', '654654', '89765464']
```

and I want to assign each *string* element as an **integer** to three variables in a single line. I tried the usual:

```
var1, var2, var3 = int(i) for i in a
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Can this be done at all or am I forced to use a for loop like the one below?

```
vars = []
for i in a:
    vars.append(int(i))
var1, var2, var3 = vars
```

Comment: You missed () around the expression: var1, var2, var3 = (int (i) for i in a)          or           var1, var2, var3 = map(int,a)

Comment: What @zhangxaochen saying `int(i) for i in a` itself an syntax error, but it a correct 'list compression' []/'generator' () expression so do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `()` or `[]` on the right hand side:

```
In [14]: var1, var2, var3 = (int(i) for i in a)

In [15]: var1, var2, var3
Out[15]: (32132, 654654, 89765464)
```

Comment: That's very strange, I could swear I tried with `[]` at least and couldn't get it to work. This works perfectly of course. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel, glad to help~ BTW, it would always be better to paste the traceback of what you've tried when post questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = ['32132', '654654', '89765464']
>>> var1, var2, var3 = map(int,a)
>>> var1, var2, var3
(32132, 654654, 89765464)
```

Comment: Not mine, I never downvote. An explanation of why this was downvoted by whoever did it would be nice.

Comment: @Rhand may be someone don't line map(), but I like small codes